# Python unittest - testing class methods fields return <built-in function input> instead of value set

Tags: python, unit-testing, python-3.x, python-unittest

I'm trying to unit test class `MyClass` method `base64DecodeInput`.
Here is some code I have:

Method in system under test class:

```
class MyClass(object):

    def __init__(self, input):
        self.input = input

    def base64DecodeInput(self):
        return base64.b64decode(urllib.parse.unquote(self.input))

    def getInput(self): # getter
        return self.input
#...
```

My test case class:

```
class TestMyClass(unittest.TestCase):

    input = 'QVNERkdISktAIyQlXiYqKDIzNDU2Nzg5MH0iPD4%2FP3s6Pgo%3D'
    decodedInput = 'ASDFGHJK@#$%^&*(234567890}"<>??{:>'

    def setUp(self):
        self.sut = myclass.MyClass(input)

    def testBase64UrlDecode(self):
        self.assertEqual(self.sut.base64DecodeInput(), self.decodedInput)

#....
```

When I run my tests:
`python3 -m unittest my_class_tests`

I'm getting
`TypeError: argument of type 'builtin_function_or_method' is not iterable`

In fact, my getter `getInput(self)` returns `<built-in function input>`.
It indicates, that the my MyClass object in not the same as I create it in the setUp method.

I'm not experienced with python, so could someone explain to me, what is going on here?

Comment: `input` is a built-in function. Change `myclass.MyClass(input)` to `myclass.MyClass(self.input)`

Comment: Thank you. That helped me a lot :)